# Updated Apple Developer Site Won't Allow Add Device to Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile April 2013

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

### Edit April 9, 2013

Apple responded to my bug report on this matter and reported that "The problem has been fixed." I have confirmed that the problem is fixed. I can now add devices to older Ad Hoc provisioning profiles that were created before the website update.

**The problem is now resolved.**

*Asside: Please note that underscore characters (`_`) are no longer permitted in the names of new provisioning profiles.*

---

As of this previous weekend April 6, 2013, it appears impossible to add devices to my existing Ad Hoc provisioning profiles on the Apple Developer [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production) page.

There are many questions on StackOverflow describing how to add devices to iOS Ad Hoc profiles, and that was a fairly straightforward task up until this weekend.

I am still able to edit the device list for my Development Profiles.

**Can anyone tell me how to add devices to my Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile on the new Apple Developer website?**

*Notes:*

- This is definitely an *Ad Hoc* profile, not a App Store
  *Distribution* profile.
- It is impossible to uncheck the radio button below: "iOS
  Distribution...".

*Edit iOS Provisioning Profile Screenshot*:
[image]

Comment: I still get jquery errors every now and then. Right now I can't add devices to an existing provisiong profiles. It hangs there with this error: "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.provisioningProfile.status'). CRAZY!!!

Comment: I can't add new devices either. The spinner keeps spinning forever after I enter the UDID/name and click continue. So frustrating!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't believe Apple could release these changes without proper testing!

Looks like you can only delete your current AdHoc profile and create a new one. While creating it you can select the devices you want. Now you can edit the device list whenever you want with the new profile.

So it looks like the format of the old and new profiles is different. I couldn't get testflight to recognize the new provisioning profiles :(

Here's a [hack you could try](https://gist.github.com/ashtom/d0aeb62eedbfd555b04e). Looks like it is working.

**EDIT:** As of **10 April 2013**, they have fixed most of the issues. The site is still too slow to load. Hope they fix that too!